# What are T Words and M Words?

Tags: english, word-property

I have two categories of English words. (Some English words are in neither category, and some are in both.) Use the examples below to determine the categories' membership criteria and explain the categories' names. The examples I give are of words that are in one category and not in the other.

| T Words | M Words |
| --- | --- |
| care | mistake |
| look | scene |
| message | conversation |
| pause | progress |
| shower | bed |
| photograph | drawing |
| dump | deposit |
| chance | wish |
| stand | move |
| chill | motion |

And a comma-separated version if that helps you:

```
T Words,M Words
care,mistake
look,scene
message,conversation
pause,progress
shower,bed
photograph,drawing
dump,deposit
chance,wish
stand,move
chill,motion
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

T words are:

> Those that can be in the form of "Take a ..."

M words are:

> Those that can be in the form of "Make a ..."

Comment: Bravo! Except that some are missing the rot13(frpbaq jbeq, gur negvpyr).

Comment: @msh210 I would consider "stand" to be an M word as well.

Comment: @hdsdv, dang, I guess you're right. Sorry, I tried to be careful.

Comment: Fun fact: There are also B words like rot13(pnxr) and R words like rot13(ynja) :P